# GitHub repo with arrow, files missing

Tags: git, github

A couple of days ago, I had to factory reset my computer due to unknown reasons causing it to slow down extremely. While looking for a way to back up all my code scripts (including small projects and other tutorials from courses, documentations etc) on a single Git Repo called `Code`. I followed instructions to push all of the files contained in that massive `Code` directory to a remote repo I created in Github, with all the projects and topics in their own sub-directories.

Today, after setting up my new computer and its environments, I cloned the `Code` repository back onto my local drive. I then wanted to get rid of version control from this local repository and turn it into a normal directory like it was before the reset. I attempted this by deleting the `.git` folder under my local repo's root directory. Then, I proceeded to go into each of the project folders contained in my Code directory and upload those as a repo of their own, starting by calling `git init` under the individual project directory. And here's where it went wrong.

After doing this with my first project folder, I found it odd that none of the files that should be under this project is not in the newly created GitHub remote repo for this project (separate from the Code repo used to back up everything). Then, so I wanted to manually get the old files from the old `Code` repo on GitHub which I thought should have my files that I had from couple days ago. But I now see a arrow when I try to navigate into this project under the `Code` repo in GitHub, like this:
[image], and cannot see the contents within this folder.

Doing some research told me that this usually happens when I initialize a git repo inside a subdirectory of another repo, so I got rid of `.git` inside this project folder in my local repo. I still see this arrow and cannot access anything inside this on GitHub. I'm desperately wondering if there is a way to get my project files back in this case? Or did I do something that is not revertible?

Comment: I left out the important part: the files are also missing from my local repo when I try to clone the entire `Code` repo again, so that's causing me to believe the files are just gone for good...

Comment: Instead of adding information in the comments (which will get buried), [edit] your post to ensure all relevant information in contained in the question.  For more info, see [ask].

Comment: Can you include a link the repository you are trying to use? It's very hard to help without any think we can actually look at or inspect.

Comment: Can you see your file in Git Hub ? If you don't update the code repo everything should still be there

Comment: The folder-with-arrow indicates a *submodule:* a reference to a separate Git repository. The superproject (which contains the arrow-thingy) simply *does not have the files in it at all* (no history, nothing, just a reference to some other Git repository). You must get those files from the other Git repository, or any clone thereof. If the only clone(s) are on your old computer, you'll need your old computer.